# How to show error message on php form validation

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, validation

I'm trying to create a registration form and validating the data submitted using PHP. But with the error messages that I've included in my PHP code, they appear on the top of the page, I would like them to appear where the default required message appears.

How the error messages appear on the page:
[image]

Heres my PHP code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

if (!empty ($_POST['fname']))
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    else{
        echo "Please enter your first name <br>";
        exit;
    }

  if (!empty ($_POST['lname']))
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    else{
        echo "Please enter your last name <br>";
        exit;
    }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";

   } else {
     $email = $_POST["email"];
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
       echo $emailErr;
     }
   }

}

   ?>
```

Heres the html code:

```
<form method="post" action="studentreg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class= sregheading>
         <h1 id = "sreg">Student Registeration </h1>

         <p>Please fill in this form to create an account to <b> attend </b> events.</p>
     </div>
       <div class="container">

         <hr>

   <label for="first name"><b>First Name</b></label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
   <label for="last name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lname" id="lname" required>

         <label for="Personal email"><b>Personal Email</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Personal Email " name="email" id="email" required>
         <label for="email-repeat"><b>Repeat Email</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Your Personal Email" name="email_repeat" id="email_repeat" required>
         <label for="Personal email"><b>University Email (p.s it should end in ac.uk)</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your University Email " name="uni_email" id="email" required>
         <label for="email-repeat"><b>Repeat University Email</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Your University Email" name="uni_email_repeat" id="uni_email_repeat" required>
         <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

         <label for="psw_repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw_repeat" id="psw_repeat" required>
         <hr>

         <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
         <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="registerbtn"/>

       </div>
```

Comment: as you need to have to use the registrationforma again, why not call the same form and have the ckeck  before inserting the data and the redirect where every you need if all is alright,lese you fill up the pfrm with the already entered data and show in red where the error is

Answer (score 1):

By assigning the errors you detect with PHP to a variable, you can check the existence of that variable in your html file and view the error wherever you want.

Heres my PHP code:

```
 <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

if (!empty ($_POST['fname']))
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    else{
        $error1 = "Please enter your first name <br>";
        exit;
    }

  if (!empty ($_POST['lname']))
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    else{
        $error2 = "Please enter your last name <br>";
        exit;
    }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $error3 =  "Email is required";

   } else {
     $email = $_POST["email"];
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $error4 = "Invalid email format";
       
     }
   }

}

   ?>
```

Heres the html code:

```
    <form method="post" action="studentreg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class= sregheading>
         <h1 id = "sreg">Student Registeration </h1>

         <p>Please fill in this form to create an account to <b> attend </b> events.</p>
     </div>
       <div class="container">

         <hr>

   <label for="first name"><b>First Name</b></label>
   <?php if(isset($error1)){echo $error1}; ?>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
   <label for="last name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
   <?php if(isset($error2)){echo $error2}; ?>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lname" id="lname" required>

         <label for="Personal email"><b>Personal Email</b></label>
         <?php 
        if(isset($error3)){echo $error3}; 
        if(isset($error4)){echo $error4}; 
         ?>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Personal Email " name="email" id="email" required>
         <label for="email-repeat"><b>Repeat Email</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Your Personal Email" name="email_repeat" id="email_repeat" required>
         <label for="Personal email"><b>University Email (p.s it should end in ac.uk)</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your University Email " name="uni_email" id="email" required>
         <label for="email-repeat"><b>Repeat University Email</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Your University Email" name="uni_email_repeat" id="uni_email_repeat" required>
         <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

         <label for="psw_repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw_repeat" id="psw_repeat" required>
         <hr>

         <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
         <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="registerbtn"/>

       </div>
```

This is my first comment, I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage more flexibility and perhaps better results if you initially configure an array mapping the field names from the form to a particular sanitising filter constant. This same array can be used for multiple operations throughout the form validation as you will see below.

Incidentally the spelling of `Registeration` is incorrect - it should be `Registration`!

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    $errors=array();
    
    #helper functions to retain form field value and display associated errors
    function setvalue( $name=false ){
        echo ( !empty($name) && !empty($_POST[$name]) ) ? $_POST[$name] : '';
    }
    function displayerror( $name=false ){
        global $errors; #import the errors variable into the scope of this function
        
        if( !empty($errors[$name]) ){
            foreach($errors[$name] as $error){
                printf('<div class="error">%s</div>',$error);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $args=array(
            # define the filters... can be more sophisticated than this!
            # the order is important for following routines where `array_slice` is used.
            'fname'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'lname'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'             =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'email_repeat'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'uni_email'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'uni_email_repeat'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'psw'               =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'psw_repeat'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'submitted'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'submit'            =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        
        # test whether all required fields are present in the POST array & have a value
        foreach( array_keys($args) as $field ){
            if( empty( $_POST[$field] ) )$errors[$field]=array( sprintf('%s is required.', htmlentities( $field ) ) );
        }
        
        # test whether there are unknown fields in the POST array - this might be malicious or developer oversight
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $_POST ) ) )$errors[$field]=sprintf('The field %s is unexpected.', htmlentities( $field ) );
        }
        
        if( empty( $errors ) ){
            # filter the POST array according to configuration above
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            
            # we are not interested in these necessarily
            unset( $_POST['submitted'] );
            unset( $_POST['submit'] );
            
            # extract sanitised POST variables
            extract( $_POST );
            
            
            
            
            # extract all the password fields & email fields into new arrays
            $pwds=array_keys( array_slice( $args, 6, 2 ) );
            $emails=array_keys( array_slice( $args, 2, 4 ) );
            $personal=array_keys( array_slice( $args, 2, 2 ) );
            $educational=array_keys( array_slice( $args, 4, 2 ) );          
            
            
            
            /* 
                validate email addresses
                ------------------------
                [1] select which fields to validate
                [2] run automated filter as basic first step.
                [3] test specific .ac.uk tld
            */
            foreach( $emails as $name ){
                if( !filter_var( ${$name}, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){
                    $errors[$name][]=sprintf('"%s" is not a valid email address!', htmlentities( ${$name} ) );
                }
            }
            
            # validate educational email tld
            foreach( $educational as $name ){
                if( substr( ${$name}, -6 ) !== '.ac.uk' ){
                    $errors[$name][]=sprintf('Invalid email "%s" - it must end with .ac.uk', htmlentities( ${$name} ) );
                }
            }
            
            # Confirm that email addresses match
            if( ${$personal[0]}!==${$personal[1]} ){
                foreach( $personal as $field )$errors[$field][]='Personal emails do not match';
            }
            if( ${$educational[0]}!==${$educational[1]} ){
                foreach( $educational as $field )$errors[$field][]='Educational emails do not match';
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            /*
                validate password length & complexity
                -------------------------------------
                complexity is NOT tested here.
            */
            $minlength=8;
            $maxlength=128;
            
            foreach( $pwds as $name ){
                if( empty( ${$name} ) )$errors[$name][]=sprintf('The password field %s is required', htmlentities( $name ) );
                if( strlen( ${$name} ) < $minlength )$errors[$name][]=sprintf('The password %s is too short! Minimum length is: %d',$name,$minlength);
                if( strlen( ${$name} ) > $maxlength )$errors[$name][]=sprintf('The password %s is too long! Maximum length is: %d',$name,$maxlength);
            }
            
            # test whether passwords match or not.
            if( ${$pwds[0]} !== ${$pwds[1]} ){
                foreach( $pwds as $field )$errors[$field][]='Passwords do not match';
            }
            
            
            
            
            # do whatever end processing with valid data is required and redirect if necessary
            # if the processing gets to this stage then all is, more or less, OK.
            if( empty( $errors ) ){
                $sql='insert into `students` () values ();';
                exit('Run: '.$sql.' and relax in a job well done');
            }
            
            
        }else{
            # display errors - the user should not see these as these 
            # are development issues or possibly malicious.
            foreach( $errors as $error )printf('%s<br />', strip_tags( $error ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Student Registration</title>
        <style>
            html,html *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:monospace}
            label{display:block;padding:0.5rem;margin:0.5rem auto;width:50%;float:none;clear:both;}
            label input{margin:auto;float:right;}
            hr{width:50%;margin:2rem auto;float:none;border:none;border-top:1px dotted grey}
            .sregheading,section{width:50%;float:none;margin:auto}
            .error{color:red;width:100%;margin:0.1rem 0;font-size:smaller;}
            .error:before{content:'*';margin:0 0.25rem;font-weight:bold}
            section{width:100%;margin:0 0 2rem 0;}
            section.footer{width:50%;margin:auto}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            removed for testing
        -->
        <!-- action='studentreg.php' -->
        
        
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class='sregheading'>
                <h1 id='sreg'>Student Registration</h1>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account to <b>attend</b> events.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class='container'>
                
                <hr />
                
                <section data-id='user-names'>
                    <label>
                        <b>First Name</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter first name' name='fname' value='<?php setvalue('fname');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('fname');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <b>Last Name</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter last name' name='lname' value='<?php setvalue('lname');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('lname');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                </section>
                
                <section data-id='personal-emails'>
                    <label>
                        <b>Personal Email</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter Your Personal Email ' name='email' value='<?php setvalue('email');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('email');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <b>Repeat Email</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Repeat Your Personal Email' name='email_repeat' value='<?php setvalue('email_repeat');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('email_repeat');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                </section>
                
                <section data-id='educational-emails'>
                    <label>
                        <b>University Email (p.s it should end in ac.uk)</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter Your University Email ' name='uni_email' value='<?php setvalue('uni_email');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('uni_email');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <b>Repeat University Email</b>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Repeat Your University Email' name='uni_email_repeat' value='<?php setvalue('uni_email_repeat');?>' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('uni_email_repeat');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                </section>
                
                <section data-id='passwords'>
                    <label>
                        <b>Password</b>
                        <input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' name='psw' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('psw');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <b>Repeat Password</b>
                        <input type='password' placeholder='Repeat Password' name='psw_repeat' required />
                        <?php
                            displayerror('psw_repeat');
                        ?>
                    </label>
                </section>
                
                <hr />
                
                <section class='footer'>
                    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href='#'>Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
                    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='true' />
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' class='registerbtn'/>
                </section>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```